# Special usage of the word 'now'

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

> The representation of Agamemnon in the epic as a whole is complex and
> variable, emphasizing **now** his generic royal qualities, **now** his genuine
> difficulties as commander of such a diverse and temperamental force,
> **now** his special personal weaknesses.

What is ***now*** doing in the above sentence? Is this grammatically correct? What is the name of this structure? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely correct. Repetition of *now* can be used to show different aspects at different points in time:

> ***now (something), now (something else)***
> ***At one time** or **in one instance** being one way, and then **at another time** being a completely different way*.
>
> - The manager keeps changing his outlook on the project, ***now*** really hopeful, ***now*** very pessimistic. ([FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/now%2C+now))

I see that not all dictionaries record this use of repetitive *now*. [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=now) does:

> At times; sometimes: ***now hot, now cold.***

So in your sentence this structure is used to mean that the representation of Agamemnon points to different aspects of his figure at different points. From the larger context it may become clearer whether this is meant to underline the thoroughness of this representation or the complexity of the character.

Comment: Also, based on observation, this use of "now" is no longer common in either colloquial or formal U.S. English...