# Why does 'tropical' mean 'figurative'?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

I came across the word ***tropical*** in a context which seemed nonsensical but, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tropical), the word can mean 'figurative' or 'metaphorical':

> **tropical**:
>
> ...
>
> 2 : FIGURATIVE sense 2
>
> ...
>
> > *an author given to high-flown tropical phrasings and convoluted symbology*

Where [*figurative* sense 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figurative) is:

> a : expressing one thing in terms normally denoting another with which it may be regarded as analogous : METAPHORICAL ...
>
> b : characterized by figures of speech

Why is the word used in this way? Is there an etymological origin unrelated to the geographical sense?

Comment: Showing that the word can be used figuratively does not mean the word means *figurative*. Used figuratively, maybe it suggests colorful or exotic, that's all.

Comment: No, Yosef, it's actually giving 'figurative' as a synonym. News to me too.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: News to me too, but the full OED has an entire section titled **II. Uses related to TROPE (noun)**. Within which is **II-3:** *Relating to, involving, or of the nature of a trope or tropes (trope n. 1); **metaphorical, figurative.*** For which the two most recent citations are dated 1984 and 2009. Unsurprisingly, *they* don't say it's "archaic"!

Comment: @FF Two exceptions do not an 'archaic' classification break.

Comment: Note the pronunciation: *"for sense 2*  ˈtrō-*"*, like *trope*

Comment: Famously used by Shakespeare in *Hamlet* IV.2. "*King.* What do you call the play? *Hamlet.* The Mousetrap. Marry, how? **Tropically**."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=tropical%20meaning&oq=tropical%20mean&aqs=chrome.0.0i131i433i512j69i57j0i512l8.4277j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) labels this meaning as *archaic*:

> ARCHAIC
> of or involving a ***trope***; figurative.

So with this meaning, *tropical* is related to *trope* which means:

> a figurative or metaphorical use of a word or expression.
>
> - Both clothes and illness became ***tropes*** for new attitudes toward the self. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=trope%20meaning&oq=trope%20mea&aqs=chrome.0.0i131i433i512j69i57j0i512l8.4167j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tropic) explains under ***tropic***:

> late 14c., "*either of the two circles in the celestial sphere which describe the northernmost and southernmost points of the ecliptic*," from Late Latin tropicus "of or pertaining to the solstice" (as a noun, "one of the tropics"), ***from Latin tropicus "pertaining to a turn," from Greek tropikos "of or pertaining to a turn or change***; of or pertaining to the solstice" (as a noun, "the solstice," short for tropikos kyklos), from ***trope "a turning"*** (from PIE root *trep- "to turn").
>
> The notion is of the point at which the sun "turns back" after reaching its northernmost or southernmost point in the sky. Extended 1520s to the corresponding latitudes on the earth's surface (23 degrees 28 minutes north and south); meaning "region between the tropics of Cancer and Capricorn" is from 1837.

It also says that in ***tropical*** is an extension of *tropic*.

As you can see, the idea of ***turn*** gave rise to two different meanings.

At this link from [Ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tropical%20phrasing%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1847%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=v0LZY8OUAs3UgQbi_KuIAw&ved=0ahUKEwiD8N2VnvL8AhVNasAKHWL-CjEQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22tropical%20phrasing%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BQgAEIAEUNEFWNEFYO8PaABwAHgAgAFGiAF7kgEBMpgBAKABAqABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books) you will find past uses of *tropical* with the meaning of "metaphorical, figurative".

Comment: Thank you. Now I also know that 'trope' means 'metaphor' as well as referring to a recurring theme.

Comment: Just keep in mind it is rare and archaic.

Comment: Certainly. Months ago, you also answered my last question, about the usage of 'now', within minutes, so thanks again!

Comment: I mean [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597632/special-usage-of-the-word-now), and I never made an account. This today is 'my' first question because I switched browsers and lost the cookie identifying me as the asker.

Comment: It's apparently ***not*** "archaic". The two most recent citations for this sense in the full OED are 1984 and 2009.

Comment: This use is most prominent in philosophy, where "trope" is a technical term in metaphysics.

Comment: @zeno You should try to [get your accounts merged](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). (And also register this account in the meantime so you don't lose access again!)

Comment: I would pronounce that *trope-ical* — with a long *o*.

Comment: A search in Google Books turns up modern examples of usage, e.g. [*tropical rhetoric*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rhetoric_and_the_Familiar_in_Francis_Bac/rqui-GZsP0IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=tropical+rhetoric&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Seeing that the PIE root is *trep-, I thought maybe German "Treppe" (stairs) is related, but seemingly it isn't

Comment: Please don't link to Google. Please link to the real source they have aggregated; if Google change their source, the link effectively breaks because it doesn't refer to Oxford any more.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't have access to the Oxford Languages Dictionaries. Neither do many users, so I am not sure how I can fulfil your request. If you have a way, please let me know.

Comment: @zeno So glad you were able to join your questions into one account. Well done!

Comment: Thanks, @fev and Laurel. I'm sure that in my future are many more questions about archaic usage.

Answer (score 10):

As Tinfoil Hat observes in a comment beneath fev's answer, the key to the mysterious second definition of *tropical* lies in the word's pronunciation. Unfortunately, the treatment of word pronunciations is not a strength of Merriam-Webster Online. The only pronunciation of *tropical* that you can play back and listen to is the traditional one for definition 1. If you look carefully, you can see that the online page for tropical lists a different pronunciation for the first syllable of *tropical* when the word is used in the definition 2 sense—but MW's presentation isn't complete (only the first syllable is given, and there is no recording of how that version of the complete word sounds).

If you had instead consulted *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), you might have had a slightly better chance of noticing the pronunciation difference:

> **tropical** \ *for 1* 'trä-pi-kəl, *for 2* 'trо̄- *also* 'trä-\ *adj* **1 a :** of, relating to, occurring in, or suitable for use in the tropics <~ foests><a ~ disease> **b :** of, being, or or characteristic of a region or climate that is frost-free with temperatures high enough to support year-round plant growth given sufficient moisture <~ Florida> **2** {L *tropicus*, fr. Gk *tropikos*, fr. *tropos* trope} : FIGURATIVE 2 [defined elsewhere in the dictionary as "**a:** expressing one thing in terms normally denoting another with which it may be regarded as analogous : METAPHORICAL **b :** characterized by figures of speech"]

Better still is the treatment in the *Seventh Collegiate* (1963):

> **tropical** *adj* **1** \ 'träp-i-kəl\ , **a :** of, located in, or used in the tropics **b** *of a sign of the zodiac* : beginning at one of the tropics **2** \ 'trо̄-pi-kəl, 'träp-i-\  {L *tropicus*, fr. Gk *tropikos*, fr. *tropos* trope} : FIGURATIVE, METAPHORICAL

A non-expert, encountering definition 2 of *tropical* in the *Seventh Collegiate*, would at least be on notice that something was odd about the pronunciation—a point easily lost in the *Eleventh Collegiate* and even more easily lost at MW Online.

But for a truly straightforward, comprehensible, and self-contained explanation of *tropical* as "figurative," I recommend the entry for *tropical* in the *First Collegiate* (1898):

> **Tropical** *a.* **1.** Of, pert[aining] to, or characteristic of, the tropics. **2.** {From TROPE} Of the nature of a trope ; figurative ; metaphorical.

Ah, yes—*Webster's [First] Collegiate Dictionary*. Now there was a useful reference work!

Answer (score 0):

I think the “sense 2” is not quite literal…and if it was it would be for sense 2b. A better definition would be “flowerly” or more mundanely “embellished”.

Tropical speech would be said with flair and panache, written using fine calligraphy and overall be amazing, although probably not quite literally true.